# Why mClient in cameraservice.h should be type of wp, but not sp?

Tags: android, android-camera

In android camera framework, the private member stands for cameraclient of class CameraService is declared as:
wp          mClient[MAX_CAMERAS];

why it claimed as wp, but not sp?

Answer (score 0):

I understand the principle now.
wp need to be promoted to sp, and then do some real work.
Sometimes the real obj may have been destructed, and wp exists, but sp is zero.